# Can we retag suspend-related questions from "sleep"→"suspend"?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Of the currently 41 [sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep)-questions, some (like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130715/using-the-echo-command-with-sleep-command)) are about the `sleep` program; the rest refer to [suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspend), as in low-power-mode; suspend-to-RAM|disk. (But few questions tagged [suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspend) are about suspending a program in a terminal with Ctrl+Z.)

I can't think of a way to denote the `sleep` command other than [sleep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep), and [suspend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suspend) is definitely the less ambiguous alternative for low-power-mode.

Am I right here?

I've suggested edits to the tag wikis to help people get them right, but having no edit-powers makes retagging tedious. Could someone more reputed have a poke?

Comment: [The question you link to](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171008/udevadm-trigger-runs-only-one-rule) is about suspending. Which of the 41 (not 11) [tag:sleep] questions is about the program? We can use the tag name [tag:sleep-command] (like we already have [tag:file-command] and [tag:mail-command]).

Comment: As an additional complication, [tag:suspend] is also used for suspending applications in a terminal (Ctrl+Z).

Comment: @Gilles Oops. I was on the "unanswered" tab, hence the wrong question counts and copied the wrong link, hence the bad example. Both fixed now.

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` should be tagged as `signals` or if it really needs to have its own tag (which I doubt) explicitly `SIGSTOP`.